# Can you please help me identify the pins that are of audio out and for the subwoofers?

Tags: electrical, audio, maruti

The image below is of the BOCSH navigation system that is pre installed in my car. I was not able to find any information about the pins from manual nor the sticker with this info is placed on removable unit.

please help me identify the pins that are of audio out and for the subwoofers and other pins. like camera, GPS, antenna etc

My Car is Maruti Suzuki Ciaz 2017 Model

[image: Maruti Suzuki ciaz pin description navigation system]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model of the vehicle this is installed into? I see you've tagged it as "maruti", which is Suzuki. Bosch provided the Nav system for these cars at some point, but not sure of their use today. Knowing what exactly this came out of will help tremendously.

Comment: My Car is Maruti Suzuki Ciaz 2017 Model

Comment: have you checked the vehicle wiring diagram? that will also tell you the pin outs possibly...

Comment: there was only one diagram for the fuses, nothing else was in the booklets provided.

Comment: Guess that the Subs are relatively grunty and older than Sat Nav . So it will be on the black loom .